# Hwo to implement QFormLayout with multiple rows and columns

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I implement a from that has multiple rows and columns?
I currently am using QFormLayout where each row is a QLabel and QLineEdit as in

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QFormLayout, QLabel,
        QLineEdit)

import sys

app = QApplication([])
win = QWidget()
layout = QFormLayout()
layout.addRow('Name:', QLineEdit())
layout.addRow('Phone:', QLineEdit())
win.setLayout(layout)
win.setGeometry(50,50,400,200)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

which renders

[image]

So if I wanted to have a form with multiple rows and columns, do I have to do something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QFormLayout, QLabel,
        QLineEdit, QGridLayout)

import sys

app = QApplication([])
win = QWidget()
layout = QGridLayout()
nameLabel = QLabel('Name:');    layout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0)
nameInput = QLineEdit();        layout.addWidget(nameInput, 0, 1)
phoneLabel = QLabel('Phone:');  layout.addWidget(phoneLabel, 1, 0)
phoneInput = QLineEdit();       layout.addWidget(phoneInput, 1, 1)
addrLabel = QLabel('Address:'); layout.addWidget(addrLabel, 0, 2)
addrInput = QLineEdit();        layout.addWidget(addrInput, 0, 3)
zipLabel = QLabel('Zip:');      layout.addWidget(zipLabel, 1, 2)
zipInput = QLineEdit();         layout.addWidget(zipInput, 1, 3)
win.setLayout(layout)
win.setGeometry(50,50,400,200)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

which renders

[image]

Is this the only way...this is not scalable.

pardon the terminology butchering ...can I have an object of type QGrid that contains two QForm objects, aligned horizontally ?
I think it means

- create a QHBoxLayout
- add a QGrid to this layout
- Grid.cell(0,0) would be QForm_a
- Grid.cell(0,1) would be QForm_b

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get. Provide  a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, I solved my problem this way.

- create a QGroupBox
- create a QGridLayout
- put a label at cell(0,0) and a lineedit at cell(0,1), then similarly at c(0,2) and c(0,3). Think of this as row-0
- Then repeat for whatever number of rows you want

I wonder what is the technical reason for QTable not allowing any widget to be inserted into a given row-col location, including a QTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Qtable widget:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
# from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'TABLE WIDGET'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createTable()

        # Add box layout, add table to box layout and add box layout to widget
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Show widget
        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
        # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.move(0, 0)

        # table selection change
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("\n")
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know about tables, learned something new. However, this solution does not seem to solve the OP, QTableWidgetItem() seems to be used for text and icons, it does not allow me to put a QLineEdit or QLabel in that cell.

Comment: For what you want I think you need to nest multiple grid layouts. A grid layout sets the layout of your widgets in the form of a grid (as the name indicates). You can use a grid layout for the 4 items you need as a kind of subform (name, address, phone and zip labels and line edits). And then you can nest this 4 items grid layouts in another grid layout as nest-deep as you like. Also there is a way to convert your .ui qt fie to python code with the batch command: "pyuic5 fileName.ui -o outPutfileName.py" in the directory where your .ui is. I find that very useful.